# issue with a scala project using maven

Tags: macos, scala, maven, jar, sbt

So I am trying to make an application written in Scala and I was trying to create a maven project using Intellj. When I was trying to compile and run my code but I've got a message saying :

> > "Error:scalac: Scala compiler JARs not found (module 'SH'): /Users/konstantinos/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.7.0/scala-reflect-2.7.0.jar" .

I tried to add the compiler from `project structure -> modules -> scala compiler` but nothing happened.

Any ideas on how to fix that? Should I swap to `sbt` and import my needed libraries?
I am trying to import `htmlunit`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary to use sbt with scala. We used maven in our project and it worked quite well.
I recommend you to install scala plugin for intellij (if you didn't do that). You can do it by File -> Settings -> Plugins.
Also you need to include Scala sdk to you project by File -> Project Structure -> Libraries -> "+" sign on the top -> Scala SDK, then you should choose scala version that stated in `scala.version` maven parameter.

I hope it will help

[image]